# How to deploy my application that i made to server ?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I have created an application using **mySQL, Express.js, React, Node.js**

My question is, which servers would allow me to deploy this application for free? I'm assuming TOMCAT wouldn't allow me to create it because I have a node.js / express.js as back-end.

Comment: I'm a little confused; you're trying to find _free_ hosting for your application?  What does TOMCAT have to do with it?

Comment: oh im just wondering im new to web development, i've looked for free web-servers such as heroku for deployments with react.js and node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of Heroku, here are a few free and easy deployment options:

Serverless:

1. AWS Lambda: https://amzn.to/2JgBFlL
2. Azure Web Services: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/cloud-services/search/?&OCID=AID719825_SEM_UHdSDoOS&lnkd=Google_Azure_Brand&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIh7rFgt2k3gIVGMNkCh0wOwnqEAAYASAAEgKkP_D_BwE

Of course in the future if you have a super lightweight 'app' you're trying to deploy, Github pages is a good option.

Serverless is a really good option though because deployment becomes as simple as pointing the serverless service to a repo and committing to the repo. The rest of the deployment process is handled by in these cases, either AWS or Azure. And for AWS and Azure, you can easily link in a lightweight, free SQL DB.

The learning curve is no less daunting than learning to deploy on Heroku, but it is much much simpler once it's set up. Plus - you get the added benefit of scalability for free because AWS and Azure takes care of it for you!

Comment: i like ur username :D and thank you for the advices :)